# Auto calculated input value with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 inputs like this :

```
<input type="text" id ="text1"/><br>
<input type="text" id ="text2"/><br>
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" disabled="disabled" id ="text3"/>
```

the 3rd input is disabled and I like that his value will equal to : **(val(text2)/val(text1)*100-100)** whene I pass the value of the two other input

so for that I try this script :

```
var p1 = document.getElementById('#text1').value;
var p2 = document.getElementById('#text2').value; 
document.getElementById('#text3').value = ((p1/p2)*100)-100;
```

but does not work , someone can help me please ?

Comment: Open your browser console, you will find errors displaying in there. `document.getElementById('#text1')` is incorrect. You don't need to have `#` in the selectors. `document.getElementById('text1')`

Comment: thanx but how can I get this value instantaneous whene I pass the two values of the other input ?

Comment: Use an event listener... `onchange` or `oninput` would work just fine.

Comment: Provided with the Solution with the help of Jquery Event Handlers. Have a Check of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `#` exists in jquery. you should type pure javascript :

```
var p1 = document.getElementById('text1').value;
var p2 = document.getElementById('text2').value; 
document.getElementById('text3').value = ((p1/p2)*100)-100;
```

Comment: Actually the `#` comes from CSS, jQuery just makes use of it. Both use it to identify the ID of an element.  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: How can I get it instantaneous just whene I pass the values of input1 and input 2 ?

Comment: @JayBlanchard `#` can also be used in `querySelector()` so it isn't just `CSS` or `jQuery`

Comment: @DhiaEddineFarah you should put it on change event of inputs.

Comment: Yep @NewToJS, which is what jQuery does under the hood. I never excluded VanillaJS from using it ;)

Comment: how can I add on change event ?

Comment: `object.onchange = function(){myScript};` or `object.addEventListener("change", myScript);`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the '#' they should not be here. The '#' is for JQuery not raw JS.

```
var p1 = document.getElementById('text1').value;
var p2 = document.getElementById('text2').value; 
document.getElementById('text3').value = ((p1/p2)*100)-100;
```

Or if you are using JQuery :

```
var p1 = $('#text1').val();
var p2 = $('#text').val();
$('#text3').val( ((p1/p2)*100)-100);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Explanation: You have used document.getElementbyID to retrieve the
>   value from the text box and the method what you have adopted is wrong.

**Method One:**

```
var p1 = document.getElementById('text1').value;
var p2 = document.getElementById('text2').value; 
document.getElementById('text3').value = ((p1/p2)*100)-100;
```

Another Method you can take is by

```
var p1 = $('#text1').val();
var p2 = $('#text2').val; 
var p3 = ((p1/p2)*100)-100;
$('#text3').val(p3);
```

> Getting the Value Instantaneously from the Inputs that has been given

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id ="text1" onblur="someFunction()"/><br>
<input type="text" id ="text2" onblur="someFunction()"/><br>
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" disabled="disabled" id ="text3"/>
```

**Javascript / Jquery:**

```
function someFunction()
{
    var p1 = $('#text1').val();
    var p2 = $('#text2').val; 
    if(p1=='' || p2=='')
    {
        alert('Please Fill all the Values');
    }
    else
    {
        var p3 = ((p1/p2)*100)-100;
        $('#text3').val(p3);
    }    
}
```

Comment: How can I get it instantaneous just whene I pass the values of input1 and input 2 ?

Comment: You can use the `onchange()` or `onblur()` jquery events to calculate the process instantaneously

Comment: how can I please do that ?

Comment: I have made the code in my solution. Have a try of that.

Answer (score 0):

Or use JQuery as you have this tag (shorter version):

```
var p1 = $('#text1').value;
var p2 = $('#text2').value; 
if(p2 != 0)
{
    $('#text3').value = ((p1/p2)*100)-100;
}
```

Don't forget to check the denominator for 0.

Comment: What if the OP hasn't included jQuery in their project?

Comment: @JayBlanchard If the OP hasn't included the `jQuery` library to their project or know how to do so then it shouldn't be tagged in the question as the OP would have no intentions of using it.

Comment: @JayBlanchard In this case I wouldn't add the answer. But he tagged as JQuery.

Comment: You would think that @NewToJS, but I have seen it over and over again.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I understand your point but that would be the OP's fault, user4035 has offered a jQuery solution as it's relevant to the tags posted so shouldn't be down to user4035 to explain every step to take for the use of jQuery unless the OP clearly stated being new to jQuery.

Comment: Now you're just arguing to argue @NewToJS. If the tag is the OP's fault there is no way for us to know that, so when we recommend an answer we should include any caveats we can think of. I just asked a simple question - what if the OP *hasn't* included the library? There is no way we can know for sure until the OP comes back saying either "It worked!" or "I am getting other errors now." I'd just rather cover the bases, know what I mean?

Comment: Further, this OP wasn't even aware to look for errors in the console @NewToJS, so....erring on the side of caution....my question is not out of line. As I've said, I have seen it over and over on this site.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Let's wait for the feedback from the OP.

Answer (score 0):

replace your code with the three lines,

```
var p1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('text1').value);
var p2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('text2').value); 
document.getElementById('#text3').value = parseFloat(((p1/p2)*100)-100);
```